# Open file with date and time stamp - Ruby Cucumber

Tags: ruby, csv, cucumber

I'm working on the CSV again!! I'm trying to get Cucumber to open it, but my problem is, everytime I download a new CSV from the webpage being developed, it adds a date and time stamp like so:

```
company_123456_export_all_20151007_074608.csv
```

Is there a way I could tell Cucumber to just open the last one? I've tried:

```
File.open(C:/Users/**/Downloads/company_#{export}_export_all_*.csv).last
```

But it doesn't like it, any suggestions?

Comment: Define 'it doesn't like it'.

Comment: It states it can't find the file and that 'last' is an undefined method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should read more about file manipulations in ruby.
For your situation you could try something like:

```
file_name = Dir.glob("C:\/Users\/**\/Downloads\/company_#{export}_export_all_*.csv").last
file = File.open(file_name, "r")
...
```

Where, first line is getting all file names and takes only last one. And second line is opening this file in read only mode.

Comment: @Tom if Yevgeniy answered your question, please mark his response as the answer. This will help others in the future.